# Multiple uses of single store on same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a store that performs a `fetch` to get graph data from my server using `asyncAction` from mobx-utils.

It looks like this:

```
class GraphStore {
    @observable
    public loading: boolean;
    @observable
    public datapoints: any[];

    @asyncAction
    *fetch(id: string) {
         const datapoints = yield fetch('/api/datapoints');
         this.loading = false;
         this.datapoints = datapoints;
    }
}
```

In my component I use it like so:

```
@inject(STORE_GRAPH)
class Graph {
componentWillMount() {
    const graphStore= this.props[STORE_GRAPH] as GraphStore;
    const { id }  = this.props;

    graphStore.fetch(id);
}
render(){
    const graphStore= this.props[STORE_GRAPH] as GraphStore;
    if(graphStore.loading)
        return <h2>Loading</h2>

    return (
       <Chart datapoints={graphStore.datapoints}/>
    );
}
```

This works great but I don't know what to do when I want to expand this to display 2 graphs on the same page?  Basically I want to have a parent component like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Graph id="foo"/>
        <Graph id="bar"/>
    );
}
```

Based on this code, the same graph store is being injected into both components, causing 2 fetches to go out and both graphs end up with the same datapoints - whichever one comes in last.

Whats the proper way to do this?  Am I just thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is `STORE_GRAPH`? Also if you are going to share store like this, my suggestion is to pass `id` or some unique key, so you can make a difference

Comment: STORE_GRAPH is a constant strong name of the store which is injected.  I added a couple extra lines of code to make that clearer.  So the best thing to do is to create multiple of the same store?  No examples do this, but is it a bad idea to pass around store constructors instead?  I kind of don't understand why stores are singletons

Comment: Stores are golden source of data. So having a singleton data means your store is immutable and hence any value received is valid. Also about creating multiple copies of store, you can create an array and create a function `getById` that would return state for current component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but I would utilize the object oriented nature of MobX, and create one data store, that is instantiated and passed down as a provider to all components. You can see this as your "local db" if you will.

Then just add methods on that data store to fetch and create different instances of Graphs.

Here's some example code (no typescript)

```
// stores/data.js

import Graph from './Graph';

class DataStore {

  @observable graphs = observable.map();

  @action getGraphById(id) {
    if (!this.graphs.has(id)) {
      this.graphs.set(id, new Graph(id))
    }
    return this.graphs.get(id);
  }

}

export default new DataStore();
```

Then create an instantiable Graph object

```
// stores/Graph.js

export default class Graph {
  @observable id;
  @observable loading = false;
  @observable datapoints = [];

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    if (!this.hasData) {
      this.fetch();
    }
  }

  @computed get hasData() {
    return this.datapoints.length;
  }

  @action async fetch() {
    this.loading = true;
    const datapoints = await fetch(`/api/datapoints/${this.id}`);
    this.loading = false;
    this.datapoints = datapoints;
  }
}
```

In your component tree you'd pass down the dataStore through the provider

```
import dataStore from './stores/data'

<Provider stores={{ data: dataStore }}>
  <Graph id="foo" />
  <Graph id="bar" />
</Provider>
```

Then just use the id prop in the component to initiate the fetch

```
@inject('data')
@observer
class Graph extends Component {

  @observable graph;

  componentWillMount() {
      const { id, data }  = this.props;
      this.graph = data.getGraphById(id);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.graph.loading) {
      return <h2>Loading</h2>
    }
    return (
       <Chart datapoints={this.graph.datapoints} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah great example, thanks.  With this solution it effectively means for each graph I display the client is storing all the datapoints in the global datastore forever..  seems its pretty common for react/redux/mobx.  Unless I ID the graphs something deterministic so opening a new one would just overwrite the old data - I don't know... I find it weird that no modern web frameworks really handle server data out of the box

Comment: You would need to handle data of multiple graphs somehow if you want to to render multiple components at once, which seemed like your question. If you are afraid of increasing memory usage over time, why not just delete the data on unmount. Actually you should checkout MobX Atoms, can be achieved automatically